# How this engine time its ignition of spark?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

HI all, do these nitro power engine use flywheel with one magnet on one side to time the ignition of the spark plug or do they use other mechanism? Thank you

Comment: In my opinion. They diesel. Once the glow plug starts the ignition during forced rotation (and accumulated cylinder temperature), (well tuned) compression ignites the fuel and inertia keeps it rotating then the glow is no longer needed. There is no magnet and coil causing spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ignition source in this type of engine is a *glow plug*, here is how it works.

The inside of the plug (which screws down into the top of the cylinder head) contains a coil of fine platinum wire. The ends of this coil are connected to a pair of electrical terminals on the outside of the plug. To start the engine, a battery is connected to those terminals, which heats up the wire, and the propeller is spun to rotate the crank and draw a charge of air and fuel into the cylinder. When the piston compresses this mixture, it heats it up and pressurizes it to the point where the hot platinum acts as a catalyst to trigger the explosion of the mixture, and the engine starts to run.

Each explosion maintains the platinum wire hot enough to catalytically trigger the next explosion, and the battery can then be disconnected.

For airplane engines about 30ccs or more in size, a conventional spark plug-and-magneto combination is used, which allows the timing of the spark to be adjusted to allow the engine to run over a greater range of speeds than is possible with glow ignition.

Comment: Hi, what is the type of fuel that is widely available in petrol station? Can I use Ron 95 fuel to power this small engine from the petrol station?

Comment: @TestingSu you should be able to answer all your questions so far by reading the manual or operating instructions supplied with the device.

Comment: @TestingSu, these motors run on petrol station gas intended for *two-stroke motorcycle engines* which has oil mixed in with the gasoline- this is NOT what automobiles run on. However, it is common to extend the lifetime of these engines by blending your own mixture of  automotive gasoline and *two-stroke oil* that is specifically compounded for use in radio-controlled airplane engines, going "heavy" on the oil proportion to better lubricate the engine. The RC aircraft community can give you guidance here. -NN

Answer (score 1):

Most of those use a glow plug which stays hot between power strokes.

Usually preheated by a power supply for starting.

Comment: Hi thanks, from what I can see is these type of engine has high power to weight ratio which makes it suitable for planes right?

Comment: This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @TestingSu, yes, this is why the radio-controlled model airplane community uses this type of engine. Note that for use in airplanes carrying *humans*,  you will want to use two-stroke engines from makers like Hirth and Rotax and decidedly NOT model airplane-type engines!!!